# Convert / Cast IEnumerable to IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class (A web control) that has a property of type IEnumerable and would like to work with the parameter using LINQ.

Is there any way to cast / convert / invoke via reflection to IEnumerable<T> not knowing the type at compile time?

```
Method void (IEnumerable source)
{
    var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();

    if (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        var type = enumerator.Current.GetType();
        Method2<type>(source); // this doesn't work! I know!
    }
}

void Method2<T>(IEnumerable<T> source) {}
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Does your `Method2` really care what type it gets? If not, you could just call `Cast<object>()`:

```
void Method (IEnumerable source)
{
    Method2(source.Cast<object>());
}
```

If you definitely need to get the right type, you'll need to use reflection.

Something like:

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(MyType).GetMethod("Method2");
MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(type);
generic.Invoke(this, new object[] {source});
```

It's not ideal though... in particular, if source isn't *exactly* an `IEnumerable<type>` then the invocation will fail. For instance, if the first element happens to be a string, but source is a `List<object>`, you'll have problems.

Comment: Depending on the situation you can also use `OfType`, just pointing out. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015930/when-to-use-cast-and-oftype-in-linq

Comment: This is also an approach for moving from IQueryable to IQueryable<T> (applicable to other such scenarios.)  Once you get moved over, you'll be able to call and use all the things you expect and need without fail.

Answer (score 11):

You probably want to refactor your code to use `IEnumerable.Cast<T>`

Use it like this:

```
IEnumerable mySet = GetData();
var query = from x in mySet.Cast<int>()
            where x > 2
            select x;
```

Comment: Requires the type at compile time. Same issue.

Comment: That is correct.  And so does Method2.  You could always cast to an IEnumerable<object>...

Answer (score 5):

With .NET 4 you can just cast `source` to `dynamic` before passing it to method. This will cause the correct generic overload to be resolved at runtime without any ugly reflection code:

```
void Method(IEnumerable source)
{
    var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();

    if (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        Method2((dynamic)source);
    }
}
```

As with Jon's second solution, this will only work if your source is actually an `IEnumerable<T>`. If it is a  plain `IEnumerable` then you'll need to create another method that converts it to the correct `IEnumerable<T>` type, as in the following solution:

```
IEnumerable<T> Convert<T>(IEnumerable source, T firstItem)
{
    // Note: firstItem parameter is unused and is just for resolving type of T
    foreach(var item in source)
    {
        yield return (T)item;
    }
}

void Method(IEnumerable source)
{
    var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();

    if (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        dynamic firstItem = enumerator.Current;
        dynamic typedEnumerable = Convert(source, firstItem);
        Method2(typedEnumerable);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is years later, but I solved the `List<Object>` problem.

```
void Method(IEnumerable source)
{
    var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();
    if (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        MethodInfo method = typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("Method2");
        MethodInfo generic;
        Type type = enumerator.Current.GetType();
        bool sameType = true;

        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            if (enumerator.Current.GetType() != type)
            {
                sameType = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (sameType)
            generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(type);
        else
            generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(object));

        generic.Invoke(this, new object[] { source });
    }
}
```