# When to use Cast() and OfType() in Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am aware of two methods of casting types to `IEnumerable` from an `Arraylist` in Linq and wondering in which cases to use them?

e.g

```
IEnumerable<string> someCollection = arrayList.OfType<string>()
```

or

```
IEnumerable<string> someCollection = arrayList.Cast<string>()
```

What is the difference between these two methods and where should I apply each case?

Answer (score 410, accepted):

`OfType` - return only the elements that can safely be cast to type x.
`Cast` - will try to cast all the elements into type x. if some of them are not from this type you will get `InvalidCastException`

**EDIT**
for example:

```
object[] objs = new object[] { "12345", 12 };
objs.Cast<string>().ToArray(); //throws InvalidCastException
objs.OfType<string>().ToArray(); //return { "12345" }
```

Comment: cheers for that. Tried both beforehand but both had elements all of the type expected hence why I could not see the difference.

Comment: @SLaks points out correctly that you should use `Cast<T>` when you know for sure that the collection contains only type `T` elements. `OfType<T>` is slower due to the `is` type check. If the collection is of type `IEnumerable<T>`, `Cast<T>` will simply cast the whole collection as `IEnumerable<T>` and avoid enumerating it; `OfType<T>` will still enumerate.

ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430570/why-is-oftype-faster-than-cast

Comment: Even in cases where `.Cast<string>()` does not throw when it is enumerated, it **is not** equivalent to `.OfType<string>()`. The reason is that **`null` values** are always skipped by `.OfType<TResult>()`. An example: `new System.Collections.ArrayList { "abc", "def", null, "ghi", }.OfType<string>().Count()` will give only `3`; the similar expression with `.Cast<string>()` evaluates to `4`.

Comment: in other words, it's something like the difference between  'as' and 'cast' operators

Answer (score 141):

Source: [LINQ Tip: Enumerable.OfType - Solutionizing .NET](http://solutionizing.net/2009/01/18/linq-tip-enumerable-oftype/)

Fundamentally, `Cast<T>()` is implemented like this:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Cast<T>(this IEnumerable source)
{
  foreach(object o in source)
    yield return (T) o;
}
```

Using an explicit cast performs well, but will result in an `InvalidCastException` if the cast fails. A less efficient yet useful variation on this idea is `OfType<T>()`:

```
public IEnumerable<T> OfType<T>(this IEnumerable source)
{
  foreach(object o in source)
    if(o is T t)
      yield return t;
}
```

The returned enumeration will only include elements that can safely be cast to the specified type.

Comment: I have provided an explicit operator, yet it still fails. Does the argument have to be of type object?
My operator expects an argument of type T, T is the type of elements in the given IEnumerable.

Answer (score 49):

You should call `Cast<string>()` if you know that all of the items are `string`s.
If some of them aren't strings, you'll get an exception.

You should call `OfType<string>()` if you know that some of the items aren't `string`s and you don't want those items.
If some of them aren't strings, they won't be in the new `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: This answer is (currently) the only one that gives an explicit advice when to use which method.

Comment: Note that `OfType<string>()` will also skip `null` values. e.g: `new string[] { "abc", "123", null, "" }.OfType<string>().Count()` equals `3`, whereas `.Cast<string>().Count()` would equal `4`.

Answer (score 8):

It should be noted that `Cast(Of T)` can be used on `IEnumerable` unlike other LINQ functions, so if there's ever a case where you need to use LINQ on a non-generic collection or list such as an `ArrayList`, you can use `Cast(Of T)` to cast to an `IEnumerable(Of T)` where LINQ can work.

Answer (score 2):

`Cast()` will try to cast all elements of the collection (and will throw an exception if element is of the wrong type) while `OfType()` will return only elements of proper type.

Answer (score 2):

`OfType` will filter the elements to return only the ones of the specified type.
`Cast` will crash if an element cannot be cast to the target type.

Answer (score 2):

`Cast<T>` will try to cast all items to the given type `T`.  This cast could fail or throw an exception. `OfType<T>` will return a subset of the original collection and return only objects that are of type `T`.