# Linq with safe cast and null verification

Tags: c#, linq, nullreferenceexception

Given the code:

```
from i in this.GridViewFoo.SelectedItems
select new EmployeeEntity
{
    EmployeeID = (i as EmployeeDto).EmployeeID,
    Email = this.GetAllEmail((i as EmployeeDto).Email, (i as EmployeeDto).SecondaryEmails),
    EmployeeNumber = (i as EmployeeDto).EmployeeNumber,
    FirstName = (i as EmployeeDto).FirstName,
    LastName = (i as EmployeeDto).LastName
}
```

After the safe cast `(i as EmployeeDto)` may I receive a NullReferenceException. How can I ensure and safety of the code and not overload him with a lot of null checks?

**Overview of solutions:**

I did some tests to assert if the solutions are working. Both are working well and bring the same result, you can check [HERE](http://ideone.com/MZGSK). After that I did some performance tests with [OfTypeSolution](http://ideone.com/vum46) and [letSolution](http://ideone.com/0SP87).

As OfType solution have better times in average, this will be the answer!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use Cast() and Oftype() in Linq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015930/when-to-use-cast-and-oftype-in-linq)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [OfType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) before the `Select`:

```
from i in this.GridViewFoo.SelectedItems.OfType<EmployeeDto>()
select new EmployeeEntity
{
    EmployeeID = i.EmployeeID,
    Email = this.GetAllEmail(i.Email, i.SecondaryEmails),
    EmployeeNumber = i.EmployeeNumber,
    FirstName = i.FirstName,
    LastName = i.LastName
}
```

it will provide you only with the `EmployeeDto` type items from the `SelectedItems` so there is no need to cast and null checking.

Comment: This avoids having numerous empty entries in the output, too.

Answer (score 2):

```
from si in this.GridViewFoo.SelectedItems
let i = si as EmployeeDto
where i != null
select new EmployeeEntity
{
    EmployeeID = i.EmployeeID,
    Email = this.GetAllEmail(i.Email, i.SecondaryEmails),
    EmployeeNumber = i.EmployeeNumber,
    FirstName = i.FirstName,
    LastName = i.LastName
}
```