# How to list all the elements from enum into IEnumerable array of the same type?

Tags: c#, algorithm, enums

I'm doing something like this.

```
IEnumerable<Poof> poofs = new[]{ Poof.One, Poof.Two };
```

I though it'd be cooler to just fetch all the elements of the *enum*, so I went like this.

```
foreach(Poof poof in Enum.GetValues(typeof (Poof)))
  Console.WriteLine(poof);
```

The above works, as far as I can see the values printed to the screen. However, when I try to store the result I get problems. Why is it so and how can I counter this?

```
IEnumerable<Poof> poofs = Enum.GetValues(typeof (Poof));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<Poof> poofs = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Poof)).OfType<Poof>()
```

Since you know all the elements are `Poof`, you can use `Cast`, but when you don't know what types do you have in the collection you can use `OfType`.The only difference between them is that `Cast`, casts the items to specified type *without a check* but `OfType` checks each type and if it is convertible to specified type then casts it and returns.It is implemented like this:

```
static IEnumerable<TResult> OfTypeIterator<TResult>(IEnumerable source) 
{
    foreach (object obj in source) {
         if (obj is TResult) yield return (TResult)obj;
}
```

Comment: This will work, but I'll prefer not to use `OfType` when we know all elements are guaranteed to be of expected type.

Comment: Oh, hard... Should I prefer *Cast* or *OfType*? Intuitively, I lean towards the latter. Casting can lead to weird stuff on occasion...

Comment: @KonradViltersten http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015930/when-to-use-cast-and-oftype-in-linq

Comment: Hehe, you should go [like this](http://bit.ly/1mREjNP) because of the laziness. I deserved it this time. :)

Answer (score 2):

`Enum.GetValues` returns an `Array` which implements `IEnumerable` and not `IEnumerable<Poof>`. So you need a cast.

```
IEnumerable<Poof> poofs = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Poof))
                              .Cast<Poof>();
```

or

```
IEnumerable<Poof> poofs = (IEnumerable<Poof>)Enum.GetValues(typeof(Poof));
```

Comment: To elaborate, `Enum.GetValues` returns a `System.Array`. You can't assign that directly to `IEnumerable<Poof>`, but you can use the `Cast<T>` method to get an `IEnumerable<Poof>`.

Comment: Why would you say *Cast* is preferable? It seems to me that casting is fully functional here but not otherwise, while *TypeOf* will always work. Am I missing something?

Comment: `OfType` will be used only when there are more types mixed in the collection. For example `ControlsCollection` will have `Button`, `TextBox` etc, in that case we use `controls.OfType<Button>()` to filter only button. Otherwise cast is preferred, we know what we're doing. We use `OfType` when we're not sure whether expected type will be there or not.

Comment: Thanks. Still, I'm not clear on **why** cast is preferred? I understand that it's **suitable** here because we know for sure about all the elements' type. However, that's only meaning it's not inferior to *TypeOf*. I sense that you argue it's superior to it. Please elaborate.

Comment: @KonradViltersten One more reason **performance**, `OfType` will perform poor as it needs to check all the elements and then cast, where as cast blindly casts. You can verify this in [source](referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs)