# Convert ICollection<Object> to another type ICollection<Person> using variable type of Type

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I try fill property type of `ICollection<Person>` or `ICollection<T>` .I give an objectList type of `List<object>` or `ICollection<object>` anyway i can't set value property type of `ICollection<Person>` by list of object

```
if (property.PropertyType.IsGenericType &&
     property.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
       == typeof(ICollection<>))
   {

      Type itemType = property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
      ICollection<object> objectList =GetObjectList();
      property.SetValue(item, objectList);


   }
```

thanks.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @DavidG: the `property` is an `ICollection<Person>`, but you can't issue `SetValue` with an object of `ICollection<object>`.

Comment: `ICollection` isn't contravariant. You can't set `ICollection<Person>` to `ICollection<object>`

Comment: Also, what is the context ? Do you really need this ? Getting over the types system is usually a sign of bad design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set an `ICollection<Person>` to an `ICollection<object>` since ICollection isn't contravariant (there is no `in` keyword in the generic parameter declaration).

You will explicitly have to cast the collection of `object` to `Person`

```
if (property.PropertyType.IsGenericType &&
 property.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
   == typeof(ICollection<>))
{
  Type itemType = property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
  ICollection<Person> objectList =GetObjectList().Cast<ICollection<Person>>();
  property.SetValue(item, objectList);
}
```

Comment: ICollection<Person> is example , in actual ,that is anonymoustype but i can accecc to the type of property by itemType (not anyway to ICollection<Person>)

Comment: @Amirhossein You can't recreate an anonymous type after casting to `object`. You will need to return a strong type

Comment: but I have itemType (Type itemType = property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];) should be away add object to list

Comment: So what? You have the `itemType` but still construct a `ICollection<object>` which is invalid. You can't add an `object` type to a collection with a derived strong type, it doesn't work.

Comment: You can try automapper.org

Comment: ohh dude that really helped me! thankx... here's 10 points reward.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is LINQ, use method `OfType` or `Cast` to cast or select objects of specified type. Since you may not convert the `ICollection<object>` to `ICollection<Person>` directly but you have a workaround to achieve the same.

```
ICollection<Person> objectList = GetObjectList().OfType<Person>().ToList();
```

or

```
ICollection<Person> objectList = GetObjectList().Cast<Person>().ToList();
```

This piece of code would return you a `List<Person>` and since `List<T>` implements `ICollection<T>` which means `ICollection<Person>` here so result will be assignable to your property

in most cases Cast() perform faster then OfType() as there is additional a type check is involved in OfType. read this for more info [When to use Cast() and Oftype() in Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015930/when-to-use-cast-and-oftype-in-linq)

**Update**

```
  object objectList = GetObjectList();
  property.SetValue(item, Convert.ChangeType(objectList, property.PropertyType));
```

this will convert the value if the types are compatible. this example does not require you to know the underlying type. read more about ChangeType http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08.aspx

Comment: I cant access to the strong type (Person)!

Comment: do you look forward to know the type as well? or you just want to set the return value of GetObjectList()?

Comment: set the return value of GetObjectList()

Comment: Yes u right,Thanks but i accepted the other answer(better for me) ,I set vote up for u

Comment: I should implement IConvertible to use `Convert.ChangeType` for each class. Is there a way to do it automatic and override class for example.