# Having trouble Getting Custom attributes

Tags: c#, attributes, sitecore, glass-mapper

I'm trying to get all attributes of each property inside a class, however I'm having trouble figuring out how to do so. I've tried a few different ways but I feel like I'm going about it wrong. Here's an example of the class and its property with attributes. Any insight would be much appreciated!

```
[SitecoreType(TemplateId= "{60E73011-0E01-4C13-A9A4-FAF8FF607930}", AutoMap= true)]
public class CalUserResults : BaseItem
{
    [IndexField("calcpa_user_name")]
    [SitecoreField("CalCPA User Name")]
    public virtual string CalUserName{ get; set; }
}
```

Specifically I'm trying to get the IndexField and SitecoreField. Thanks!

Edit things I've tried...

```
 CalUserResults kf = new CalUserResults();

 Glass.Mapper.Sc.Configuration.Attributes.SitecoreFieldAttribute attribute = kf.
     GetType().
     GetMethod("CalUserName").
     GetCustomAttributes(false).
     Cast<Glass.Mapper.Sc.Configuration.Attributes.SitecoreFieldAttribute>().
     SingleOrDefault();
```

and

trying by using FieldInfo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOURCE OF THE PROBLEM:**

LINQ `Cast<T>` method tries to cast each of the attributes in the `IEnumerable` to the given type. And it fails, because your method has another attribute of `IndexField` type. That's why you are getting the [InvalidCastException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidcastexception(v=vs.110).aspx) while executing the query.

**SOLUTION:**

What you need to solve the problem is to use the LINQ [`OfType<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx) method. It filters the `IEnumerable` based on the success of cast operation:

```
 Glass.Mapper.Sc.Configuration.Attributes.SitecoreFieldAttribute attribute = kf. 
     GetType().  
     GetProperty("CalUserName").
     GetCustomAttributes(false). 
     OfType<Glass.Mapper.Sc.Configuration.Attributes.SitecoreFieldAttribute>(). 
     SingleOrDefault();
```

**P.S.:** Also you may want to read [When to use Cast() and Oftype() in Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015930/when-to-use-cast-and-oftype-in-linq) to clarify the issue and improve the understanding of LINQ.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the oftype is actually helpful but one of the major problems i realized is that i need to do "getproperty" not "getmethod" but still helpful! Thanks :)

Comment: Oh, yes. I haven't seen.