# How to convert Array of objects into an IEnumerable of inheriting object?

Tags: c#

I have `PInfo2[] pInfo` and need to use it as an `IEnumerable<PInfo3> betterInfo` where `public class PInfo3 : PInfo2`

What I've tried, but doesn't work:

```
(IEnumerable<PInfo3>)pInfo //Runtime error: "Unable to cast object of type 'PInfo2[]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[

IEnumerable<PInfo3> betterInfo = pInfo as IEnumerable<PInfo3>; //Always null after cast.
```

What am I doing wrong, aka how am I being dumb? Do I need to for-loop through the array? I don't know why but I was hoping I didn't have to do that.

Comment: try `pInfo.Cast<PInfo3>()`. That is in the `System.Linq` namespace, in case you don't have it in your file.

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem... and clarify what you want to happen if there are non-`PInfo3` items in the collection.

Comment: @krillgar cool, that totally works, thanks :) I knew I was being a dumbass.

Comment: Sooo... etiquette question, do I provide an answer to my own question here then or? I know I can, but should I?

Comment: @krillgar Are you going to post that as an answer? It is the right one. OP, etiquette is to ask the user to post it as an answer.

Comment: Failing that, edit your question to make it clear that you have an answer (and state what the answer is), so people reading this question know it's been answered without reading the comments.

Comment: Sorry @BradleyDotNET , got called away to lunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ to cast the objects of the enumeration to a different related type.

```
pInfo.Cast<PInfo3>();
```

Now, this can cause some issues if there are some elements in the collection that can't be cast, but there are ways around that as well (see Edit):

<strike>`pInfo.Select(p => (PInfo3)p).Where(p => p != null);`</strike>

The `Cast` should be used when you **know** that the conversion will succeed, and the second when there could be elements that can't make the conversion.

**EDIT**

Per Daniel A. White's comment below, there is also the `.OfType<T>()` method, which will only get the items that match the requested type, and avoid the `IllegalCastException` that `Cast<T>()` will throw.

For additional details, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4015967/1195056).

Comment: Have a look at `.OfType<..>`.

Comment: Nice! I have not had to use that before.