# How to efficiently filter elements in the List based on values in another list

Tags: c#, linq

I have list of cars and list of rentals of those cars. Every rental has `DateTime From` and `DateTime To` and `Car Car` properties.

I would like to exclude from list of cars, those cars which are unavailable at the chosen period. The beginning and end of this period are values of two `DateTimePickers`.

I achieved my goal by this code:

```
  public void FilterAvailableCars() {             
            List<Car> cars = ObjectPlus.Objects[typeof(Car)].Select(o => (Car)o).ToList();               
            List<Rental> rentals = ObjectPlus.Objects[typeof(Rental)].Select(r => (Rental)r).ToList();          
            foreach (var rent in rentals) {
                if (fromDateTimePicker.Value < rent.To && rent.From < toDateTimePicker.Value) {
                    cars.Remove(rent.Car);
                }            
            }
            carListBox.DataSource = cars;               
        }
```

I mixed LINQ and for loops, but I would like to know how pure and efficient LINQ solution would look like.

Comment: You seem to understand Linq, so I am unsure of what you are having difficulty with. You are familiar with `Where` in Linq, yes? Or is this an efficiency question?

Comment: Don't convert every function to linq.  Your code should be easily understandable.  Complicated linq statements make code hard to maintain.  I don't see the need to change your current solution.

Answer (score 1):

First, you select all the rental cars based your condition:

```
  var rentalCars = rentals.Where(rent => 
                  fromDateTimePicker.Value < rent.To && rent.From < toDateTimePicker.Value)
      .Select(r => r.Car);
```

Then, use `Except` method to get the result:

```
  carListBox.DataSource = cars.Except(rentalCars);
```

Comment: Is my solution in comment below Sinatr post is more efficient? It is corrected code from Sinatr answer.

Comment: @Yoda: Yes, your commented code is more efficient :)

Answer (score 1):

Few fixes:

```
// filter rentals within entered date
var rentals = ObjectPlus.Objects[typeof(Rental)].Cast<Rental>()
    .Where(rent => fromDateTimePicker.Value < rent.To && rent.From < toDateTimePicker.Value);
// filter rented cars 
carListBox.DataSource = ObjectPlus.Objects[typeof(Car)].Cast<Car>()
    .Where(car => !rentals.Any(rent => rent == car)).ToList();
```

Use [`Cast/OfType`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4015930/1997232) and do filtering with single `Where` (creating list and removing items from it as you do is kind of inefficient).

I don't know how efficient is `Except`, if you don't instantiate query result (using `ToList()`) then it should be same efficient.

It may be more efficient (depending on number of items of `Rental` and `Car`) to check for cars inside rental's `Where`.

Comment: This is corrected code, working:      `public void FilterAvailableCars() {
            var rentals = ObjectPlus.Objects[typeof(Rental)].Cast<Rental>();
            carListBox.DataSource = ObjectPlus.Objects[typeof(Car)].Cast<Car>()
                .Where(car => !rentals.Any(rent => rent.Car == car && fromDateTimePicker.Value < rent.To && rent.From < toDateTimePicker.Value)).ToList();`
        }

Comment: Right, see edit. I am not sure whenever `ToList()` on rentals is better (will take more memory, but will be faster).

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way usually is to correlate the data using `join` (or [antijoin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Antijoin_.28.E2.96.B7.29) like in your case):

```
var rentals = ObjectPlus.Objects[typeof(Rental)].Cast<Rental>()
    .Where(rent => fromDateTimePicker.Value < rent.To && rent.From < toDateTimePicker.Value);
carListBox.DataSource = 
    (from car in ObjectPlus.Objects[typeof(Car)].Cast<Car>()
     join rent in rentals on car equals rent.Car into carRentals
     from carRent in carRentals.DefaultIfEmpty()
     where carRent == null
     select car).ToList();
```