# Count all columns start with special name in C#

Tags: c#

I have a DataTable have all columns like:

`B0_1   A1_1   B0_2  A1_2  B0_3  A1_3   B0_4   A1_4`

How to count only columns start with `A1_`?

I had variably contains `A1_x` like this:

`nameCol + n.ToString() + "_" +`

Note: In this example you can see `A1_1 -> A1_4` but 4 is randoms number, about from 1 -> 9.

Comment: Count what ? The number of column ?

Comment: `columns.Count( col => col.Name.StartsWith("A1_") && col.Name.Length == 4 )` ?

Comment: I want to count only columns start with `A1_x` with 1 < x < 9.

Comment: @user3185569 What else can u count....?

Comment: @User2012384 Sometimes people say "count" when they mean "sum". Or you could count unique values in the columns. Or unique values in _all_ columns.

Comment: So given your example the outcome of the count would be 4, right?

Comment: Do you want to know the amount of columns? Or count something regarding those cells' contents?

Comment: Thanks, all people. #user3185569 and #compuchip were helpful me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using Linq:

```
  DataTable table = ...

  int result = table.Columns
    .OfType<DataColumn>()
    .Count(column => column.ColumnName.StartsWith("A1_"));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... You awesome!

Comment: It would be better to use `.Cast<DataColumn>()` instead of `.OfType<DataColumn>()` because you don't need filter the elements. Read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015930/when-to-use-cast-and-oftype-in-linq) the difference between these two methods.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is one option to match the post-fix restriction (`A1_x` with `1 < x < 9`):

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("A1_a"); // out
dt.Columns.Add("A1_6"); // in
dt.Columns.Add("A1_5"); // in
dt.Columns.Add("A1_7"); // in
dt.Columns.Add("A1_0"); // out
dt.Columns.Add("A1_1"); // out
dt.Columns.Add("A1_9"); // out

// count result is: 3

var count = (from col in dt.Columns.OfType<DataColumn>()
             where Regex.IsMatch(col.ColumnName, "A1_[2-8]")
             select col).Count();
```

You need to add `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;` to use the `Regex` type.

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ

```
int count = table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                  .Count(c => c.ColumnName.StartsWith("A1_"));
```

Using foreach

```
int count = 0;
foreach(DataColumn dc in table)
{
    if (dc.ColumnName.StartsWith("A1_"))
        count++;
}
```