# Operation to combine Where and Cast in LINQ

Tags: linq

Is there a more succinct way to write this:

```
var targets = collection
    .Where(x => x is ITarget)
    .Cast<ITarget>();
```

It seems like there should be a way to combine the calls the `Where` and `Cast` into a single operation. However, perusing `Enumerable` turns up no likely candidates.

Does such a LINQ operation exist or is this the only way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you're looking for [`OfType<>()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Excerpt:

> Filters the elements of an IEnumerable based on a specified type.

```
System.Collections.ArrayList fruits = new System.Collections.ArrayList(4);
fruits.Add("Mango");
fruits.Add("Orange");
fruits.Add("Apple");
fruits.Add(3.0);
fruits.Add("Banana");

// Apply OfType() to the ArrayList.
IEnumerable<string> query1 = fruits.OfType<string>();

Console.WriteLine("Elements of type 'string' are:");
foreach (string fruit in query1)
{
  Console.WriteLine(fruit);
}
```

output:

> Mango
>
> Orange
>
> Apple
>
> Banana

So Reading: [When to use Cast() and Oftype() in Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015930/when-to-use-cast-and-oftype-in-linq).

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. I knew it made sense for something like that to exist, just missed it when looking.