# Select values from DataGridViewCellCollection using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `DataGridViewCellCollection` and want to read the values from the cells. Later I want to create a new object, pass in these values as constructor parameters and add them to a list.

```
        List<Connection> connections = new List<Connection>();

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataGridViewCellCollection cells = dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells; // current cellrow
            int firstValue = (int)cells[1].Tag; // convert to int
            int? secondValue = (int?)cells[0].Value; // convert to nullable int
            connections.Add(new Connection(firstValue, secondValue));
        }

        return connections;
```

`Connection` itself represents this `struct`

```
internal struct Connection
{
    public Connection(int firstID, int? secondID)
    {
        FirstID = firstID;
        SecondID = secondID;
    }

    public int FirstID { get; private set; }
    public int? SecondID { get; private set; }
}
```

I would like to rewrite this code with `Linq` but how can I select specific multiple values and cast the result to an object?

Comment: Could you please post the class definition of `Connection`?

Comment: Sure, sorry, I updated my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<Connection> connections = dataGridView.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
             .Select(x => new Connection((int)x.Cells[1].Tag, (int?)x.Cells[0].Value)
             .ToList();

return connections;
```

As suggested by @Mark Schultheiss, using `.Cast<DataGridViewRow>` can be faster as below.

```
List<Connection> connections = dataGridView.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
             .Select(x => new Connection((int)x.Cells[1].Tag, (int?)x.Cells[0].Value)
             .ToList();

return connections;
```

Comment: `.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()` may be faster since we can assume the rows of that type perhaps? https://stackoverflow.com/q/4015930/125981

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Thanks for comment. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
from row in datagridView.Rows
let cells = row.Cells
let firstValue = (int)cells[1].Tag
let secondValue = (int?)cells[0].Value
select new Connection(firstValue, secondValue)
```

Comment: I'm sorry but `Rows` got no select method. Do I have to convert it?

Comment: It should be `dataGridView.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>()` instead of `datagridView.Rows`

Comment: or cast it `.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()`

Answer (score 1):

```
var connections = dataGridView.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
.Select(r => new Connection((int)r.Cells[1].Tag, (int?)r.Cells[0].Value))
```

Comment: I just need to convert `Rows` to something that got a `Select` method because `Rows` has no. And I'm not able to convert `Rows` to a list

Comment: Well, now I can add comments. Make sure you are using System.Linq :)

Comment: It should be `dataGridView.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().Select(...)` instead of `datagridView.Rows.Select(..)`

Comment: I formatted so I could see it easier, Not sure if the OP wants it realized with `.ToList()` but it seems so?

Comment: @andy fill more/all of your profile out for a few extra points :)

Comment: Thanks @RuiJarimba, I missed that part completely.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Connection> connections = dataGridView.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
                                           .Select(CreateConnection)
                                           .ToList();
```

Or:

```
var connections = from row in dataGridView.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
                  select CreateConnection(row);
```

Method CreateConnection:

```
private Connection CreateConnection(DataGridViewRow row)
{
    var firstValue = (int) row.Cells[1].Tag;
    var secondValue = (int?) row.Cells[0].Value;

    return new Connection(firstValue, secondValue);
}
```