# If object O inherits from object T, how can I convert List<O> to List<T>?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, poco

I have a JSON response that depends on a POCO C# object I can't directly modify.  I need to add some fields to the POCO object, and then mask them from any other component of the application that reuses the same object.

Since I control both the webserver, and the client, (but not the POCO object itself), My solution is to derive from the object T, creating `List<O>`, and then convert that to `List<T>` for any dependency that doesn't want to see my additions within derived object `O`.

If `T` is a parent of `O`, and simple casting doesn't work, how should I convert from one to the other?

e.g.

```
public class Parent
{
  public string ParentString {get;set;}
}

public class Child : Parent
{
   public string ChildTempObject {get;set;}
}


public static DoStuff()
{
   List<Child> childList = new List<Child>
   //... get from webservice...
   return (List<Parent>)childList; // doesn't work
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Enumerable.Cast<T>`:

```
List<Parent> parentList = childList.Cast<Parent>().ToList();
```

Comment: `OfType` vs `Cast` is discusssed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015930/when-to-use-cast-and-oftype-in-linq)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to convert the contents of the array to the parent:

```
List<Parent> parentList = childList.ConvertAll(x => (Parent)x);
```