# Type cast a base list to derived list within a LINQ query

Tags: c#, performance, linq, inheritance, casting

So let me go through the scenario of what I'm trying to do.
I have four classes(representing documents in my business), with a common base class, 'DocumentBaseClass'.
This base class contains a property "type" among 2-3 other properties.
There's a set of data in cosmos db, that contains all the data against these models.
I need to retrieve all of it, with only one trip to DB and then store in SQL DB in their tables(of their respective models)
Therefore, I am applying a linq query on the entire result received.
The linq query filters all the data where the type is of the specific document and since this is of the base type and I need the derived class for the data to be added to their table, I am type casting it to that specific class.
I have yet to test it, that is another long process.

Now my questions are,
1.Is my linq query efficient?
2.And is the casting correct?
3.Is there any way to make is more efficient?

```
Expression<Func<DocumentBaseClass,bool>> predicate = x => x.id == id; // the id passed to the function
var result = await _cosmosDBClient.GetItemsAsync(predicate);
var derivedClassARecords = result.Data.Where(cb => cb.Type=="DerivedClassA").Cast<DerivedClassA>();
var derivedClassBRecords = result.Data.Where(cb => cb.Type=="DerivedClassB").Cast<DerivedClassB>();
```

After this a service is called for each type that will add data to their respective tables.

```
foreach (var item in derivedClassARecords)
{
    _derivedClassBService.Process(item);
}

foreach (var item in derivedClassBRecords)
{
    _derivedClassBService.Process(item);
}
```

Comment: `Where()` returns `IEnumerable<T>`and you are trying to typecast it to `DerivedClassA/B`, will it even work?

Comment: Have you tried `.OfType<ClassName>()`? With classes inherited from a base class that might work better than `.Where().Cast<>()` See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=net-5.0) for more info

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar, Yes, b/c apparently the data types of for eg.,derivedClassARecords is IEnumerable<DerivedClassA>. I checked through intellisense

Comment: @David784, No, let me try that.
But how does it work better?
Can you briefly explain the difference between two that makes it better?

Comment: @David784, I am asking because I have read their difference; that unlike Cast, typeof will try to cast only the elements that can be casted to the desired type.
But how does that make any change here, when I am first getting only those records that have a type as the desired type?

Comment: That question has already been addressed [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015930/when-to-use-cast-and-oftype-in-linq). But briefly, you're doing two operations. You loop through once to filter, and then a second loop to cast. `OfType` can do both steps in a single operation...it can filter AND cast in one step.

Comment: @David784, thanks for the explanation

Comment: @David784 That is not _quite_ accurate. `Where` returns an `IEnumerable` that filters its source, but only one element at a time. `Cast` is the same, but changes the type. So until you use `derivedClassARecords` in a situation that requires the elements, there is no looping. When you do, there is just one loop, requesting each element from `Cast` which requests each element from `Where` which requests from its source. So using `OfType` saves on the nested method calls to `Cast`,`Where`, and the filter lambda method, but at the expense of `is` which may or may not be more efficient.

Comment: @David784 See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7324095/2557128) on deferred execution.

Comment: @Alina Does `GetItemsAsync` really return instances of `DerivedClassA` and `DerivedClassB` or are all the elements of type `DocumentBaseClass`? In the latter case you won't be able to simply cast the elements. Another question regarding efficiency is, how do you plan to use `derivedClassARecords` and `derivedClassBRecords`? Enumerating only once? Using linq is not necessarily the best way in your case.

Comment: @Steeeve,
GetItemsAsync returns instances of DocumentBaseClass
Do you have any suggestion on how to do it, if casting won't work and it doesn't.
"how do you plan to use derivedClassARecords and derivedClassBRecords?", need to add in their respective tables in sql db.
Why isn't linq the best way to enumerate?

Comment: If you can't change GetItemsAsync to deliver the proper instances, you will need to create new instances of DerivedClassA and DerivedClassB depending on the value of the Type property. Linq is ok, if you would enumerate the results only once. If you would need it more times, creating two lists of the needed types and filling them with a single enumeration of GetItemsAsync could be more efficient.

Comment: Yes, so basically all in all there will be a total of 5 derived classes of document types that would be extracted from the list received from GetItemsAsync.
That is why we were trying to get all the data at once, instead of five trips to cosmos db.
GetItemsAsync, get data from cosmos db.
And that db contains data that is for each table.

Comment: I would need some more input to decide how to proceed. But if you have 5 possible document types and you need separate IEnumerables for the proper types (to be created from DocumentBaseClass instances), I would use a single foreach loop on GetItemsAsync and fill 5 lists with the proper instances. Maybe you can show a bit more code telling why do you need instances of DerivedClassA, B,... and not DocumentBaseClass which already should have every information for the derived classes.