# How does one convert from an IEnumerable to IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, active-directory, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

Is there a way to get an `IEnumerable<T>` from an `IEnumerable` without [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812673/convert-cast-ienumerable-to-ienumerablet), assuming I know the type at design time?

I have this

```
foreach(DirectoryEntry child in de.Children)
{
   // long running code on each child object
}
```

I am trying to enable parallelization, like so

```
Parallel.ForEach(de.Children, 
    (DirectoryEntry child) => { // long running code on each child });
```

but this doesn't work, as de.Children is of type [`DirectoryEntries`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentries.aspx). It implements `IEnumerable` but not `IEnumerable<DirectoryEntry>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way to achieve this is to use the [`.Cast<T>()` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx).

```
Parallel.ForEach(de.Children.Cast<DirectoryEntry>(), 
    (DirectoryEntry child) => { // long running code on each child });
```

Another way to achieve this is to use the [`.OfType<T>()` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx).

```
Parallel.ForEach(de.Children.OfType<DirectoryEntry>(), 
    (DirectoryEntry child) => { // long running code on each child });
```

There is a subtle different between `.Cast<T>()` and `.OfType<T>()`

> The OfType(IEnumerable) method returns only those elements in
>   source that can be cast to type TResult. To instead receive an
>   exception if an element cannot be cast to type TResult, use
>   Cast(IEnumerable).

-- MSDN

This link [on the MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/05aa30b9-f0ef-4080-b76a-1a127afc0a9d/) got me going the right direction.

Comment: @KooKiz: But pointless if you know that every element is a `DirectoryEntry` anyway. `OfType` filters and casts, so if you need to filter use `OfType` otherwise `Cast`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Somehow, I always believed that `OfType` was faster than `Cast`. Don't ask me why. Anyway, I've just searched a bit and discovered that `Cast` is faster. So indeed, my remark was pointless.