# Collection to delimited string

Tags: vb.net, string, object

when I do

```
String.Join(";", lst.Items)
```

I get a string of object descriptors instead of item of values.
But when I iterate the collection, I end up with a delimiter at the front or back and need to a Substring call afterwards.

```
    Dim res As String = "" 'or use stringbuilder
    For Each s As String In lst.Items
        s &= ";" & s
    Next
    res = res.Substring(1)
```

This applies to other cases as well where you want to turn a shared property within a collection into a delimited string. Is there a nice way to do this?
Can I do this with LINQ and would it be faster?

Comment: no, ObjectCollections expose already the IList interface, but they contain Objects rather than strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
    Dim res As String = String.Join(";", lst.Items.OfType(Of String))
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to convert the items to strings then:

```
String.Join(";", lst.Items.Select(Function(item) item.ToString()));
```

Comment: +1, but technically, I'd refer to `ToString` as *converting*, not *casting*.  `DirectCast` is *casting*.  Pretty much everything else in VB.NET, including `CType` and `ToString`, could only be accurately be described as converting.

Comment: ty, I picked dbasnett's as the answer cause I expect it to be a bit faster even than LINQ

Answer (score 0):

This does work:

```
    Dim col As New Collection
    col.Add("One")
    col.Add("Two")
    col.Add("Three")

    Dim res = String.Join(";", col.OfType(Of String))
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14238523/why-do-so-many-named-collections-in-net-not-implement-ienumerablet)

Comment: The array is already made, I want to take a property of the elements into a delimited string, without explitl rebuilding

Comment: I added the building of the collection just as an example, because your question didn't contain which kind of collection your question is about. And a Collection is not the same as an array.