# Create a method to work on IEnumerable of all types (type unknown at design run-time)

Tags: c#, generics

I know this is most probably a simple question involving Generics, or, quite possibly, just a big "no-no" overall, but I'm curious to see if I can get this working.

I'm trying to create a method that takes in an `object` and, if the `object` is an enumerable type, to pass it off to a method that can work on any kind of enumerable, but I'm getting terribly stuck.

My current code for the method that takes in an object looks something like the following:

```
private void MyMethod()
{
    Dictionary<string, object> MyVals = new Dictionary<string,object>();

    ... fill the MyVals dictionary ...

    object x = MyVals["Val_1"];
    Type type = x.GetType();

    // Check if we have a series of values rather than a single value
    if (type != typeof(string) && typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(type))
        Test(x);
}
```

Then, I thought I could write *something* like one of the following as the method signature for my `Test` method:

**1. Write it as if it's an IEnumerable of object:**

```
private void Test(IEnumerable<object> MyEnumeration)
```

Tried calling it via:

```
Test((IEnumerable<object>)x);
```

Leads to run-time error that it cannot cast from `IEnumerable<int>` to `IEnumerable<object>`

**2. Try using Generics:**

```
private void Test<T>(IEnumerable<T> MyEnumeration)
```

Tried calling it via:

```
Test(x);
```

Leads to design-time error that the signature is incorrect / invalid arguments.

or via:

```
Test<type>(x);
```

Leads to a design-time error that the type or namespace `type` could not be found.

---

How could this be done OR is it just bad programming practice and there is a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: No reason why either fails from looking at the signature. However, "neither works" is a *terrible* explanation of what is going on, and that makes this really hard to address. What specifically doesn't work when you try this, and what in general is the Test method attempting to accomplish?

Comment: Fair enough, @TravisJ. Let me update my question...

Comment: Question updated with my attempts - Hope that makes (at least a bit) more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with this code:

```
if (type != typeof(string) && typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(type))
    Test(x);
```

You now know that `x` is an IEnumerable, but it still treated as an `object` when the compiler determines which method signatures are compatible.

If you did this:

```
if (type != typeof(string) && typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(type))
{
    IEnumerable asEnumerable = (IEnumerable)x;
    Test(asEnumerable);
}
```

Then it can be passed to

```
void Test(IEnumerable t)
{
}
```

Or, if you really want to use `IEnumerable<object>`:

```
if (type != typeof(string) && typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(type))
{
    IEnumerable<object> asEnumerable = ((IEnumerable)x).Cast<object>();
    Test(asEnumerable);
}
```

And, if you want an `IEnumerable<T>`, see Jon Skeet's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/812699/25216) to a different question.

Comment: @TravisJ Correct. I'm just solving option one. You need Jon Skeet for option two: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812673/convert-cast-ienumerable-to-ienumerablet

Comment: Yes, actually you at least included the option for the IEnumerable<T> usage so I removed my comment. And I agree that using Jon Skeet's suggested type inference approach is the best way to call when there are issues with making a type inference call.

Answer (score 0):

This has a bad code smell so I would elaborate what it is you actually want to do and maybe someone can help. Your runtime error is due to the fact the collection you have is in fact NOT an `IEnumerable[object]` but is `IEnumerable[int]`. You would have to call `.Cast<object>` first.

So it would be a double cast.

```
Test(((IEnumerable<int>)x).Cast<object>);
```

Again, this has a terrible code smell. You should elaborate how the data is coming in and I am sure someone can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should create two overloads of Test() method. one which would handle `IEnumerable` and another which handles `IEnumerable<T>`. *Why do you need method overload?* Because `IEnumerables` are not generic `IEnumerable<T>` and at run time you won't be knowing the type of generic type to use `Cast` on `object`.

Below is the sample showing how exactly you can achieve what you're looking for:

```
 public void MyMethod()
 {
     // Sample object with underlying type as IEnumerable
     object obj1 = new ArrayList();

     // Sample object with underlying type as IEnumerable & IEnumerable<T>
     object obj2 = (IList<string>)new List<string>();

        if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(obj1.GetType()))
        {
            if (!obj1.GetType().IsGenericType)
            {
                // Handles case of IEnumerable
                Test((IEnumerable)obj1);
            }
            else
            {
                // Handles case of IEnumerable<T>
                InvokeGenericTest(obj2);
            }
        }
 }

 public void Test(IEnumerable source)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Yes it was IEnumerable.");
 }


 public void Test<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Yes it was IEnumerable<{0}>.", typeof(T));

     // Use linq with out worries.
     source.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
 }

 /// <summary>
 /// Invokes the generic overload of Test method.
 /// </summary>
 /// <param name="source"></param>
 private void InvokeGenericTest(object source)
 {
     Type t = source.GetType();

     var method = this.GetType().GetMethods().Where(x => x.IsGenericMethod && x.Name == "Test").First();

     var genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(t.GenericTypeArguments.First());
     genericMethod.Invoke(this, new object[] { source });
 }
```